# Blackberry parse String in format yyyy-MM-dd to Date

Tags: date, blackberry, java-me, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I've tried using the HttpParserDate.parse method but in one device (Blackberry Pearl 9100) I get the error

```
Error starting App: Class 'net.rim.device.api.io.http.HttpDateParser' not found.
```

I'm using the BlackBerry JDE 6.0. Is there a way to parse the date and be available on all devices??

Answer (score 1):

You may have noted that BlackBerry state that you should develop on an OS level that is the same or earlier than the devices you are are targeting.  So in this case, because you are using JDE 6.0, you should deploy compiled apps on OS 6.0 devices and above.

You will find a comment to this effect on this page:
[Eclipse download](http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/download/#eclipse)

I believe that the 9100 was originally released using OS 5.0, but is upgradeable to OS 6.0. To check what level your handset is running, look in the Options - About.

Both OS 5.0 and OS 6.0 contain HttpDateParser.  My suspicion in this case is that you have compiled in OS 6.0, so it will not work on a OS 5.0, but your 9100 is running OS 5.0.  If so, you have two choices, develop using OS 5.0, or upgrade your 9100.

BTW, I have deliberately given you the download page for Eclipse.  I used to use the JDE but Eclipse is a much nicer development environment, if a little more difficult to get to grips with initially.  If you are planning to d a lot of development, then I would encourage you to try Eclipse, and you can install a JRE to support OS 6.0 and/or OS 5.0.  Alternatively, you might want to install JDE 5.0.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It says that is running 6.0 package 2390 (v6.0.0.534)

Comment: @rod_torres.  That is very odd.  I need to think about this.

Comment: @rod_torres That class is included since OS 4, so it must be a different problem, probably a misconfigured  development environment. I'm not sure what IDE you are using since you mentioned the good old JDE, but on the other hand you've tagged the question with the blackberry-eclipse-plugin tag.